# Wordpress - Loop out posts found in an array of ID numbers

Tags: php, wordpress, list, loops

I have a list of post id's which I would like to loop the posts for, I have tried using the WP_QUERY with post__in, but this does not keep the order that the id's are listed in inside the $sorted array.

What is the simplest way of looping an array of id's as posts, but overriding the natural post order for the order that the $sorted array is listed?

```
$args = array (
    'post__in'  => $sorted, // array of id's that I want in order
    'posts_per_page'    => -1, // so that it shows everything in the array
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1 // so that stickys dont affect order
);



$query = new WP_Query( $args );

// The Loop
if ( $query->have_posts() ) {
    echo '<ul>';
    while ( $query->have_posts() ) {
        $query->the_post();
        echo '<li>n' . get_the_title() . ' - '. get_the_ID () .'</li>';
    }
    echo '</ul>';
} else {
    _e( 'Sorry, no posts matched your criteria.' );
}

wp_reset_postdata();
```

Comment: you mean to say you want post order by post id right ?

Comment: @sameer-sheikh No in the order that the ID's in the array $sorted are listed. Overriding the natural post order.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just use 'orderby' => 'post__in'

```
<?php 
$postsArgs = array(
    "post_type" => "post",
    "orderby" => "post__in",
    "order" => "ASC",
    "posts_per_page" => "-1",
    "post__in" => array(1,8,6)
);
$posts = new WP_Query($postsArgs);
?>
```

Comment: No not in the order of the ID's in the order that the $sorted array is (the problem is that it is sording in order of the post id's even when the sort by ID is omitted. How would I ignore the natural post order and display them in the order of the $sorted aray)

Comment: Ok, got it, updated my answer.
use
        'orderby' => 'post__in'
instead